# Is there a way to list all supported locales either the C- or C++-runtime?

Tags: c++, c, localization

I'm curious about the supported locales of my C- and C++-runtime. So is there a way to list the supported locales for either the C- or C++-runtime ?

And if there isn't: are there platform-dependent ways that map 1:1 to the C- or C++-runtime locale-strings for either Linux or Win32 ?

[EDIT1]: What I'm asking for isn't given in the answers you referred to. Windows's EnumSystemLocalesEx() doesn't directly map to the C-/C++-locale-strings because the locale-strings lack the encoding (like ".UTF8"). And for Linux I don't want to list the locales via the commandline, but via system-APIs.